# How to get how many of each item is in a list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure how to get how many of each item is in a string.  Like for example:

```
{"harley": ["apple", "apple", "banana"]}
```

So how would I get this:

```
Harley has Apple x 2 and Banana x 1
```

Comment: Take a look at [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: Lists also have a `count` method, but if you want to count all the things, it's much less efficient.

Comment: Hmmm. Looks like collections.Counter is pretty good for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

d = {"harley": ["apple", "apple", "banana"]}
for k,v in d.items():
    print("%s has %s" %(k, ', '.join("%s x %s"%(k,v) for k,v in Counter(v).items())))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {"harley": ["apple", "apple", "banana"]}

from collections import Counter
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print k + ' has ' + ' and '.join('{0} x {1}'.format(name, count) for name, count in Counter(v).iteritems())
```